# Trouble deploying python on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I forked some code from GitHub and am trying to get it working as an app on Heroku. I'm pretty new to coding so your help is greatly appreciated!

My goal is to get the code from GitHub (booking bot) to run so my boss can make tennis court reservations automatically. He likes to play at certain times and the reservations get taken within seconds of being released. I found this code that seems like it will solve the problem and am hoping to get it running.

I was able to deploy it on Heroku by connecting to GiHub and made some of the changes necessary but I'm getting this message:
Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.

Here's a link to the app on Heroku:
https://gary-reserve.herokuapp.com/

Here's a link to my fork on GitHub:
https://github.com/GaryKentTeam/booking_bot

Thank you for your help! a

Comment: Hi, all. Just wanted to post an update. I figured I'm in over my head on this one and found someone to write the program for us. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to add some logs, it could be any number of things.

Paste the results from Heroku logs --tail.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. Here's what I'm seeing:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Pz5yYYtocjOn9KQ0j-CA9pI4C9YQU02Ga613ZDx2OPs/edit?usp=sharing